# Selected Value of Dropdown in VB.NET

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, drop-down-menu

I have the following dropdown in my page:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="cboEmployerType" runat="server" TabIndex="8" Width="60%" onclick="javascript:shouldsubmit=false;">
                       <asp:ListItem Value="Null">-Select-</asp:ListItem>
                       <asp:ListItem Value="E">Employer</asp:ListItem>
                       <asp:ListItem Value="O">OJT Provider</asp:ListItem>
                   </asp:DropDownList>
```

When I click a certain button, my dropdown should have selected value as **-Select-**. How do I do this?

I tried this in my code behind but doesn't work.

```
cboEmployerType.SelectedValue = "null"
```

Comment: cboEmployerType.SelectedIndex = 0 or cboEmployerType.SelectedValue = "Null"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set

```
cboEmployerType.SelectedIndex = 0
```

This will select your first value.

Comment: Yes, I shall do when it allows me too.

Comment: @Aishvarya,what does this mean you cant accept answer for your question?

Comment: You can't accept an answer rightaway - it takes some time. Hope you know it.